# What is the distinction between a full node and a miner?

Tags: mining, nodes

I know that in the Ethereum network miners have to be full nodes, and I know that a full node somehow runs the entirety of the protocol. But what does that mean, precisely?

The whitepaper says miners have to store the full blockchain so they can verify any randomly chosen prior transactions, but full nodes only have to store the state. Do full nodes only verify the most recent block? Why would anyone do this without the incentive of mining?